# Is it possible to create a MULTIBOOT USB with Kali + persistence?

Tags: partition, kali-linux, gparted, persistence

I am using the Live version of Kali Linux and now I'm realizing that having persistence might be a good idea. There are some tutorials out there showing how it can be done on Windows and it looks easy with tools like Rufus. However the thing is that I have a Multiboot USB containing some other ISOs like one for a live GPARTED distro that allows me to resize all partitions on my computers. For this setup, I am using a tool called Ventoy. Now, Ventoy does support persistence as written [here](https://www.ventoy.net/en/plugin_persistence.html) but the instructions were rather difficult for me to follow. I was wondering if I could simply partition the drive myself into two volumes: one for ventoy + GPARTED + Kali and the other for the live Kali persistence? What extra would I need to put in the second (persistence) partition to tell Kali to use that space for its persistence storage?

What would be the best way of going about this. What I finally want is a multiboot USB with two ISOs: one for GPARTED, one for live Kali + persistence, quite possibly in two partitions (or more if required). Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ventoy is a fantastic option, and it sounds like you might be halfway there already with setting up a drive. Have you tried Ventoy's configuration tool, [Plugson](https://ventoy.net/en/plugin_plugson.html)? It's browser-based and runs on your local machine, providing a point-and-click configuration for some of the trickier stuff, like persistence files.

Ventoy's partition layout is pretty specific, I wouldn't mess with it after the drive is configured. Persistence is stored in separate flat files, not another partition.

I cannot speak to other approaches, but the [official Kali linux docs roaima suggested](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/) would probably be a good place to start.